# Check box in table header need to hide,when all checkboxes in other rows is hidden

Tags: jquery, css

Checkbox in table header need to hide,when all check boxes in other rows is hidden.

```
if ($('#Submit').css('display', 'none')) {
                                $("#chselect").hide();
                            }
                            else if($('#Submit').css('display') == 'none'){
                                $("#chselect").show();

                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

your solve is simple my friend :

1- in first you need to add class and called it `checkboxes` to all checkboxes except the header's checkbox

2- add id `mainCheckBox` to header's chechbox

3- add this code

```
$(".checkboxes").change(function() {
    var flag = false;
    $(".checkboxes").each(function () {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) { 
           flag = true;
        }
    });
    if(flag == true)
    {
        $('#mainCheckBox').attr('checked', "checked");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#mainCheckBox').removeAttr("checked");
    }
});
```